# aws alarm when metric is same for past

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, metrics, alarm, threshold

I want to raise an alarm in AWS whenever 24 hours have passed without the value of the metric changing (all datapoints pushed the same number for the last 24 hours).

How could I achieve that?

Was thinking of trying something like

`IF(m1 == PREVIOUS(m1), 1, 0)`